# Валидация типа загружаемого файла в моделях Django

Tags: python, django

Я хотел чтобы с админ панели могли добавляться только mp4 файлы, для этого я установил python-magic, но я без понятия куда поставить эту проверку, ведь файл ещё не загружен. Попытки установить его в поле модели FileFild(validators=...) приводили к ошибки что ожидаемый объект не FieldFile

Вот мой код моделей

```
import magic

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import ValidationError, FileExtensionValidator


# Create your models here.
def valid(data):
    if magic.from_file(data, mime=True) != 'application/mp4':
        raise ValidationError('No no no')


class Xvideo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=30, null=False)
    description = models.TextField('Описание', max_length=1000)
    file = models.FileField('Видео', upload_to='media/', null=False, validators=[valid])
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя пользователя', max_length=30, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerField('Возраст')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField('Пол', max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField('Комментарий', max_length=1000, null=False)
    users = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xvideo = models.ForeignKey(Xvideo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.name
```